# Nicely formatted numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How do I do the following in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

```
DECLARE @PCT Decimal(4,1)
SET @PCT=3.1
SELECT 
WHEN @PCT = CAST(@PCT AS Int) THEN CAST(CAST(@PCT AS Int) AS Varchar)
ELSE CAST(@PCT AS Varchar) END AS newPct
```

I'm trying to drop the .0 if the percent ends in a whole number.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this in SQL instead of your calling applicaton?

Comment: I put all my logic as close to the data as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will work if you add the CASE keyword

```
DECLARE @PCT Decimal(4,1)
SET @PCT=3.1
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @PCT = CAST(@PCT AS Int) THEN CAST(CAST(@PCT AS Int) AS Varchar)
    ELSE CAST(@PCT AS Varchar) END AS newPct
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because I'm also adding a WHEN @PCT IS NULL THEN '0' clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to a float first.  The rules for casting from a float to a varchar are different from the rules for a decimal to a varchar.  The following seems to work for me:

```
select cast(cast(@PCT as float) as varchar) as 'newPct'
```

Comment: Casting to a `float` then back again seems like an unneeded potential for lost precision

Comment: Generally, I'd agree with you, but if you're starting with a `decimal(4,1)` I don't think there's anything to worry about... though I could be wrong...

Comment: I think in this instance it is OK, but it still worries me to see it :)